# How to add onclick event to dynamic a href with jquery

Tags: jquery

For example i have such code:

```
$("#total").html("Price $<span>" + value + "</span>");
```

And i also want to add a href button there

```
$("#total").html("Price $<span>" + value + "</span><a id='remove' href='#'>remove</>);
```

But how i may add `onclick` event for that a href?

**UPDATE**

I really like that solution:

```
//Create the link to remove the item beforehand, and add the onclick event handler.
var removeLink = $("<a id='remove' href='#'>remove</a>").click(function(e) {
    //Click event handler here.
});

$("#total").html("Price $<span>" + value + "</span>");  //Create the price value
$("#total").append(removeLink);  //Add the remove link.
```

Because there is a lot of remove links going to be on my form, but i have a question how to pass any parameters to that click function in such case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
//Create the link to remove the item beforehand, and add the onclick event handler.
var removeLink = $("<a id='remove' href='#'>remove</a>").click(function(e) {
    //Click event handler here.
});

$("#total").html("Price $<span>" + value + "</span>");  //Create the price value
$("#total").append(removeLink);  //Add the remove link.
```

It's a bit more verbose than a one liner, but it's very readable in my opinion.

---

In response to your comment below, if you want to pass parameters, you can do it in many ways. Since you're using Jquery, there are two main ways I can think of off the top of my head:

**Method 1: Taking avantage of anonymous functions being able to access variables in outer scope**

```
var param = 1234;                // <-- We know this value before we create the link
var removeLink = $("<a id='remove' href='#'>remove</a>").click(function(e) {
    var someVariable = param + 4321;
    alert(someVariable);        //Shows "5555" in a message box when link is clicked.
});
```

**Method 2: Using [jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/)**

```
var param = 1234;                // <-- We know this value before we create the link
var removeLink = $("<a id='remove' href='#'>remove</a>").click(function(e) {
    var someVariable = jQuery.data(this, 'param') + 4321;
    alert(someVariable);        //Shows "5555" in a message box when link is clicked.
});
jQuery.data(removeLink, 'param', param);    // <-- Save the param as a Jquery data value
```

Comment: any ideas how i can pass param to that click function ?

Comment: @Joper - I've updated my answer to give two examples of how you could pass a param into the click function. There are a few different ways in which you could do it, but these are two of the most common ones when using Jquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a it a few ways, `live()` is one example, or..

```
$("#total").html("Price $<span>" + value + "</span><a id='remove' href='#'>remove</a>");
$("#remove").click(function() { /* ... */ });
```

or

```
$("#total").html("Price $<span>" + value + "</span><a id='remove' onclick='doSomething();' href='#'>remove</a>");
```

As well as other ways using the set assignment or chaining, etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#total").html(
    $("Price $<span>" + value + "</span>").append(
        $("<a id='remove' href='#'>remove</a>").click(function(){
            // Click Handler
        })
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by using a simple JQuery **find** function and **click** handler:

```
 var h = $("#total").html("<span>Price $<span>" + value + "</span><a id='remove' href='#'>remove<a/></span>");
 h.find('a').click(function() { alert('hello') });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using chaining

```
$("#total").html("Price $<span>" + value + "</span><a id='remove' href='#'>remove</>).find(">a").click(function(){
   //on click code goes here
});
```